# Vue: reinitiating Vue after fetching new components and inserting them into HTML

Tags: javascript, dom, vue.js, rendering

Is it at all possible to force Vue to re-initiate itself, after I have fetched a component from an API and inserted it into the DOM?

By component I mean:

```
<div><My_component /></div>
```

Which is a part of a BE snippet.

And inserting it into HTML:

```
document.getElementById("something").innerHTML = "<div><My_component /></div>"
```

I have tried the `.$forceUpdate()` function, but that just returned undefined and did nothing.

I cant get the newly added component to get recognised by Vue. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use dynamic components for what you need.

Here is quick syntax.

**JSON**

```
var items = [
  {component: 'TextComponent', params: {x: 1, y: 2}},
  {component: 'BoxComponent', params: {a: 3, b: 2}}
]
```

**Vue Template**

```
<component :is="item.component" v-for="item in items" v-bind="item.params" />
```

**Will Render to**

```
<TextComponent :x="1" :y="2" />
<BoxComponent :a="3" :b="2" />
```

Comment: The problem is that my component is inside a backend HTML snippet, surrounded with other HTML and this snippet as a while is send to FE and inserted into the DOM. Would this still apply?

Comment: I dont think its possible, but you can turning your html to json might help. https://jew.ski/himalaya/ - https://github.com/andrejewski/himalaya

Comment: @Jousi check $compile, i believe it is what you are looking for. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile